# 'Make' command not found (associated with Less)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, node.js, makefile, less

I Installed Nodejs, then installed the LESS command line compiler.

```
    $ npm install -g less uglify-js
```

From here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html#compiling

Now getting the following error when i run the `Make` Command.

```
    sh.exe": make: command not found
```

Any clues why? Thanks much!

Comment: Are you running `Make`, or `make`?

Comment: hi Dave, sorry meant 'make'... either one though, doesn't work.

Comment: I assume you are in windows and you don't have the unix `make` utility.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a GNU `make` utility available. You can get make in many ways:

- get Make for Windows http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm
- get cygwin on Windows and install the make package http://www.cygwin.com/
- use a Linux virtual machine, which probably will have GNU make installed by default

I'm sure there are other possibilities as well, these are the ones I can think of right now.