# node-gyp install error on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, node.js, ubuntu-12.04, node-gyp

I keep getting this error message when I'm trying follow the directions on https://github.com/rwldrn/johnny-five. I'm trying to install this library for NodeBots day and I'm having problems. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on WMware Virtual Machine. I thought it had to do with Arduino serialport lack of detection but I fixed that grey out error.

It seems to be a node-gyp problem. What could it be and what can I do?

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-   gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-27-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/euridice/johnny-five/node_modules/serialport
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.15
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.6
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! weird error 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Make' command not found (associated with Less)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658983/make-command-not-found-associated-with-less)